# Service worker registeration failed when indexed in google search console

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, google-console-developer

While indexing react web app on google console google bot is showing this error:

```
Whoops. Service worker registration failed, error: Error: Rejected at ServiceWorkerContainer.wrsParams.serviceWorkers.navigator.serviceWorker.register (<anonymous>:10:852) at s (https://ssr-static.mywebsite.com/v19.7.7-1815-geb247de9e/static/bundle.ba64e845.js:2:828484) at https://mywebsite.com/v19.7.7-1815-geb247de9e/static/bundle.ba64e845.js:2:828253

https://ssr-static.mywebsite.com/v19.7.7-1815-geb247de9e/static/bundle.ba64e845.js:2
```

Service worker registration working fine when viewed in browser.

How can this be fixed for google web cache?

Comment: you're not going to be able to 'fix this'. Googlebot does not register or care about your service worker. Google's search index is only concerned about the rendered markup as a result of are request for the URL.
Anything done in your service worker is moot to google. I don't even think they enable the feature in their rendering engine, which is why it fails for your.
So don't worry about the error.

Comment: @ChrisLove Thanks. I also felt same after reading a few related articles. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In place of Google, I would make a fake registration of an Service Worker so that I do not receive an error message in the console.  I don't know if this is possible in their case.

Comment: @AndreyK. can you give a code example, please?